Status of "extra" mitzvot
When the Jews are exiled to Babel, God commands Jeremiah to tell the Jews some instructions regarding their behavior in exile (Jeremiah 29:4-9):

"Thus said GOD of Hosts, the God of Israel, to the whole community that I exiled from Jerusalem to Babylon: Build houses and live in them, plant gardens and eat their fruit. You should take wives and beget sons and daughters; and you should take wives for your sons, and give your daughters to husbands, that they may bear sons and daughters. Multiply there, do not decrease. And seek the welfare of the city to which I have exiled you and pray to GOD in its behalf; for in its prosperity you shall prosper. For thus said GOD of Hosts, the God of Israel: Let not the prophets and diviners in your midst deceive you, and pay no heed to the dreams they dream. For they prophesy to you in My name falsely; I did not send them—declares GOD."

So this isn't from the Torah, and it isn't a Rabbinic mitzvah. What is it? Is it a sin if one transgresses it?

See Rambam on what it is when a prophet issues an situational edict from Hashem

https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.29a.1?lang=bi&with=all

https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.52b.11?lang=bi&with=all

https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.30b.9?lang=bi&with=all

Jeremiah 29 is directed at everyone but 32 is directed only at Jeremiah, it's only something that can be done once, and God didn't actually command anything).Yet both of these are used as sources for permanent halachot in Sholom's gemaras.
Or are these not sources, but rather explanations for why Rabbis made certain rabbinical enactments?
I still don't know whether 29 is a permanent mitzvah, a long standing temporary mitzva, or a recommendation.

See commentaries on Lech Lecha - Avraham was fulfilling a command of Hashem.

Which  commentary and which verse in particular. It's a big parsha?

@ClintEastwood I mean't on the pasuk with Lech Lecha. I don't know which in particular but I am just giving ideas
